# Why is flex-flow: column wrap not working as expected?

Tags: css, flexbox

In this example, I'm trying to use `flex-flow: column wrap` in tablet media query, to let **Section Three** fall under **Section Two** and **Section Four** fall under **Section Three**... I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? Instead, there's a large gap under **Section Two**.

```css
/* Roboto Font */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700&display=swap');

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
}

html {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

main {
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  main {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    height: 10000px;
  }
}
section {
  margin: 24px 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  section {
    flex: 50%;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
  }
}

article p {
  margin: 16px 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <section>
      <h2>Section One</h2>
      <article>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi nisi earum cupiditate error animi nesciunt quas, a possimus enim dignissimos deleniti autem non reiciendis assumenda culpa dolores quis nulla eveniet.</p>
        <p>Veritatis at tenetur explicabo reprehenderit adipisci, nisi alias, dolores illum quibusdam fugiat dolorem corrupti facilis aspernatur quae cum odit eveniet, neque quisquam quam suscipit iste. Amet provident cum id quasi!</p>
        <img src="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F13%2F2015%2F04%2F05%2Ffeatured.jpg&q=60" alt="">
        <p>Nihil quibusdam provident optio unde eaque asperiores est veritatis repudiandae officia distinctio deleniti fuga facere modi ipsam autem cum deserunt, facilis quia accusantium labore illum possimus corporis! Fugiat, mollitia vitae.</p>
      </article>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>Section Two</h2>
      <article>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Alias eaque, impedit sint nobis dolore non porro accusantium ullam quas eligendi sequi suscipit nemo cumque quisquam ipsa harum nam beatae nesciunt!</p>
        <p>Tenetur odit libero in ea odio hic voluptatibus amet officiis. Est unde quae ipsam in veritatis alias at ipsa sapiente delectus neque. Quis officiis minus quibusdam voluptate? Praesentium, recusandae libero.</p>
        <p>Quod ipsum fugit saepe nisi at quae iure culpa magni, voluptatibus consectetur enim adipisci quo repellat ad est a eos voluptatem tenetur dolorem dolore! Ab iure tenetur dignissimos laborum officiis!</p>
      </article>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>Section Three</h2>
      <article>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Alias eaque, impedit sint nobis dolore non porro accusantium ullam quas eligendi sequi suscipit nemo cumque quisquam ipsa harum nam beatae nesciunt!</p>
        <p>Tenetur odit libero in ea odio hic voluptatibus amet officiis. Est unde quae ipsam in veritatis alias at ipsa sapiente delectus neque. Quis officiis minus quibusdam voluptate? Praesentium, recusandae libero.</p>
        <p>Quod ipsum fugit saepe nisi at quae iure culpa magni, voluptatibus consectetur enim adipisci quo repellat ad est a eos voluptatem tenetur dolorem dolore! Ab iure tenetur dignissimos laborum officiis!</p>
      </article>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>Section Four</h2>
      <article>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Alias eaque, impedit sint nobis dolore non porro accusantium ullam quas eligendi sequi suscipit nemo cumque quisquam ipsa harum nam beatae nesciunt!</p>
        <p>Tenetur odit libero in ea odio hic voluptatibus amet officiis. Est unde quae ipsam in veritatis alias at ipsa sapiente delectus neque. Quis officiis minus quibusdam voluptate? Praesentium, recusandae libero.</p>
        <p>Quod ipsum fugit saepe nisi at quae iure culpa magni, voluptatibus consectetur enim adipisci quo repellat ad est a eos voluptatem tenetur dolorem dolore! Ab iure tenetur dignissimos laborum officiis!</p>
<p>Tenetur odit libero in ea odio hic voluptatibus amet officiis. Est unde quae ipsam in veritatis alias at ipsa sapiente delectus neque. Quis officiis minus quibusdam voluptate? Praesentium, recusandae libero.</p>
        <p>Quod ipsum fugit saepe nisi at quae iure culpa magni, voluptatibus consectetur enim adipisci quo repellat ad est a eos voluptatem tenetur dolorem dolore! Ab iure tenetur dignissimos laborum officiis!</p>
      </article>
    </section>        
  </main>
```

Comment: For the column to wrap it must have a defined height so it knows when to wrap.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work here. Each column has a different amount of content in it.

Comment: You only have one column on `main`, that won't wrap until it has a height, then it will *seem* to have additional columns.

Comment: I've added a height to `main`, but it just extended the height of the container, and it didn't wrap anything. I've updated the snippet above.